# How to create a custom map by plotting only certain addresses or points in an online Web mapping service like Google Maps etc. for printing

Tags: google-maps, printing, customization

For example, for any city, I want to create a **A4 printable map**, showing **only** specific addresses (like important areas of a city). Such a map will show which direction each area falls, optionally distance between them & how the **city layout looks with those areas**.

Another example is plotting top n attractions of a city.

Since in general what we get for a [city map](https://goo.gl/maps/pfMmI) will be zoomed such that it’s difficult to locate the areas of interest in printable format as it will show lot of areas scribbled.

Comment: @pnuts may be,yeah.

Answer (score 1):

Pending a better offer, perhaps http://veloroutes.org/upload/ is better than nothing.

[image: WA61047 example]

Answer (score 0):

This is almost two different questions and things you are looking for.
First is creating or having a detailed location on Google maps.  Something similar to this...

The Home Depot
4139 Transit Rd, Buffalo, NY 14221

https://maps.google.com/maps?cid=18144410920963866014&hl=en%e2%89%b7=us&shorturl=1

Now this example is one store, a Home Depot, with many different departments and areas identified and aisles and such.  Here you can search for directions to the help desk or garden center or someplace else. But expand this concept across the city or certain businesses is what is sounds like you are asking.
A client of mine (not home Depot, I don't know what they see and I am not affiliated with them, I had just recently used that feature) is using Scribble Maps (https://www.scribblemaps.com ) to draw the areas, label them, put images on them and then then export it and upload to Google Maps.  That could be an option.

The second thing you are asking for (so it sounds like) is a formatted printed page.
If the area of the map has the content would that be ok?  Regardless of print format or how many pages it goes on?  Because with the upload tland process from Scribble Maps those items will show up, but Google maps has a layering system with those things and there is already issues with getting a regular Google maps to print exactly as you want it regardless of the layers.  Getting things to print is relatively easy, if it's there and selected it will print.  You mY need to to adjust the layers and some settings.  But depending on how you are looking at the map and want to print it, that can add some nuances making more difficult.